# Links to figures points to the label and not in the image

Tags: floats, hyperref

When I click on a link in my table figure, the link points to the label and not directly in the image. I need to scroll up for see the image.

How solve this problem?

Here's how I implement my figures:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{img/asymetric.jpg}
\end{center}
\caption[Public-key cryptography]{Public-key cryptography}
\label{Public-key cryptography}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that makes the situation happen? If you include it, we can replicate the situation and try to suggest a solution, otherwise there is not much we can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `hycap` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}
\begin{document}
Go to figure \ref{yyy}
\newpage
\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{15cm}
\caption{xxxx\label{yyy}}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You just need add `\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}`. The [documentation](http://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/hypcap.pdf) says "Option all enables the redefinitions of all four float environment" but for me I need to add the option figure and table like this: `\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}`